# Деактивация кнопки при заполненном поле

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, button, submit

Имеется форма и одно поле-ловушка, которое не будет отображаться для пользователей, нацеленное на ботов, цель, деактивировать кнопку отправки если бот что-то туда вставил.

поле-ловушка

```
 <textarea class="form-message" name="user_message" id="trap" onkeyup='checkParams()' cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
```

кнопка формы

```
<button class="form-btn" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Send</button>
```

(атрибут disabled сейчас кнопке прописан чтобы корректно работал код-донор в его нынешней редакции)

Есть код-донор, который в случае незаполнения поля оставляет кнопку неактивной, при заполнении активирует:

```
function checkParams() {
    var trap = $('#trap').val();

    if(trap.length != 0) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
}
```

как сделать наоборот:
чтобы кнопка с загрузкой страницы была активная, но при заполнении поля #trap деактивировалась?

Вот что пытался делать:
1. Изначально в html теге кнопке атрибут disabled не задавать.
2. Код:

```
function checkParams() {
    var trap = $('#trap').val();

    if(trap.length > 0) {
        $('#submit').setAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'false');
    }
}
```

Но тогда кнопка срабатывает в обоих случаях

Comment: При использовании такого поля нужно не форму блокировать, а проверять это поле на бекенде. js может вообще не работать у бота

Comment: Ребят, зачем вы для таких простых задач используете jquery? Без этой библиотеки кода примерно столько же будет.